# How to open or run Edge in 32-bit mode?

Tags: windows-10, 32-bit, microsoft-edge

I have an old web application that I can no longer open. There is no update or newer version available, yet it controls some rather important hardware so I still need to use it.

I cannot open the web application in Firefox or Chrome, but I can open it in Edge. After logging into the web application however, it tries to open some kind of control (I'm guessing ActiveX?) which fails, and it presents the error "ViewXCtrl is not supported in the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer. Please use the 32-bit version.".

After trying to open the website in Internet Explorer (both the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version), IE automatically switches to Edge, which is apparently always in 64-bit mode because no matter what version I open, I always get the above message.

How can I open Edge in 32-bit mode on Windows 10 or, if that isn't possible, how can I still open this web application without having to result to virtual machines or similar?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147647/discussion-on-question-by-joe-how-to-open-or-run-edge-in-32-bit-mode); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally figured out how to run this web application in Edge.

First I changed the settings in Edge where I allowed sites to be opened in IE-mode.
Second I added the URL to the web application to the list of pages that are allowed to be opened in IE-Mode.
The last step was to open the website, log in, click on the IE icon in the top bar, log in again, and then the ViewXCtrl controls became visible.

Apparently the message "ViewXCtrl is not supported in the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer. Please use the 32-bit version." is incorrect, as the application is now running in 64-bit Edge.

I hope this procedure helps, should anyone come across the same message.